# Japa Sankalpam for Australia ( Melbourne)

Tags: rituals, sankalpa

I've been meaning to do Sandhya vandhanam but I don't know what words to use instead of "Bharata Varshe" "Bharata Khande ". Can anyone please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Even for the Dvipa part, there is some confusion i guess.. some say it's Kusha Dvipa, but others say that it is not correct.. What does ur Guru say in this regard?

Comment: I don't have a guru. I wouldn't be asking this question if I had one

Comment: Without a Guru how are u doing the ritual??

Comment: As far as I know, Bharat Varsha mentioned in the Puranas is not India or the Indian subcontinent. Bharat Varsha is actually the whole world. If you read the descriptions of these regions in the puranas you'll notice that Bharat Varsha is the only place where the four yugas comes into play and also it's the only place where there is diseases, short life span, fruition of stored karma's etc. The rest of the Varshas of jambudwipa like Uttarakuru Varsha , ilavrita Varsha, Kimpurusha Varsha, Hari Varsha etc. are places where  lifespan of intelligent beings are 1000 years and have no diseases.

Comment: So Bharat Varsha is the whole world. It's the earth that we're familiar with. Whereas Bharat Khanda IMO is the Indian subcontinent. I could be wrong about Bharat Khanda, but thats my opinion ... Then there are the other dwipas like krauncha, pushkara, kusha etc. These are not part of the earth.

Comment: Bharat Varsha,  the whole world is further sub divided into nine regions in Markandeya Purana. When rishi Markandaya was explaining about the region of Bharata to his disciple, he said that there are 9 sub regions of Bharata. The ninth one was the place where they (rishi Markandeya and his disciples lived). This ninth sub region is mentioned in Vishnu purana as Yahadweep. So it could be one of the continents of our known earth.